# Branch contract calls

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito

I'm trying to replicate the contracts call for the raw found below:

```
{ "branch": 
        "BMLgLBqf6dxFBNMLBBDkVtNSJCfQMcNxLiEmUKRmE8bYFrKY1CW", 
        "contents": 
        [ 
            { 
                "kind": "transaction", 
                "source": "MY TEZOS ADDRESS", 
                "fee": "1000", 
                "counter": "29412399", 
                "gas_limit": "8000", 
                "storage_limit": "250", 
                "amount": "0", 
                "destination": "CONTRACT ADDRESS ONE", 
                "parameters": {    
                    "entrypoint": "update_operators", 
                    "value": 
                    [ 
                        { 
                            "prim": "Left", 
                            "args": 
                            [ 
                                { 
                                    "prim": "Pair", 
                                    "args": 
                                    [ 
                                        { "string": "MY TEZOS ADDRESS" }, 
                                        { 
                                            "prim": "Pair", 
                                            "args": 
                                            [ 
                                                { "string": "ADDRESS 1" }, 
                                                { "int": "VALUE" } 
                                            ] 
                                        } 
                                    ] 
                                } 
                            ] 
                        } 
                    ] 
                } 
            }, 
            { 
                "kind": "transaction", 
                "source": "MY TEZOS ADDRESS", 
                "fee": "1500", 
                "counter": "29412400", 
                "gas_limit": "10000", 
                "storage_limit": "250", 
                "amount": "0", 
                "destination": "ADDRESS 1", 
                "parameters": 
                { 
                    "entrypoint": "offer", 
                    "value": 
                    { 
                        "prim": "Pair", 
                        "args": 
                        [ 
                            { 
                                "prim": "Pair", 
                                "args": 
                                [ 
                                    { "string": "VALUE" }, 
                                    { "int": "VALUE" } 
                                ] 
                            }, 
                                    
                            { "prim": "Pair", 
                            "args": 
                            [ 
                                { "int": "VALUE" }, 
                                { "int": "VALUE" } 
                            ] 
                        } 
                    ] 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

The below code is what I got for now:

```
async myFunction() {
        let contractOne = await this.tezos.contract.at("CONTRACT ADDRESS ONE");
        let contractTwo = await this.tezos.contract.at("ADDRESS 1");
        let batch = await this.tezos.wallet.batch()
            .withContractCall(contractOne.methods.update_operators([{0: {add_operator: ["MY TEZOS ADDRESS", "ADDRESS 1", "VALUE"]}}]))
            .withContractCall(contractTwo.methods.offer("VALUE", "VALUE", "VALUE", "VALUE"));
        try {
            var batchOp = await batch.send();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("got this error", error)
        }
        console.log(batchOp)
        await batchOp.confirmation();
    }
```

I keep getting this error (I won't paste all of it as it is quite long but let me know if you need me to add it):

```
message: 'Http error response: (400) Failed to parse the request body: No case matched:\n'
status: 400,
  statusText: 'Bad Request',
```

Not sure what to try from now, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The contract call to `update_operators` seems to have the wrong parameters, try:

```
update_operators([{ add_operator: ["MY TEZOS ADDRESS", "ADDRESS 1", "VALUE"] }])
```